# How to change variable value in a function of Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

The code:

```
function send_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
         key = 3; %this is the variable
         current = str2double(get(handles.value, 'String'));
         %value is a textbox where user put input
         newValue = key+current;
         set(handles.listbox1,'String', newValue)
         %listbox1 is a listbox to show the value
         %Now I want to replace the value of key by the value of current
         %key = current - something like this
```

**What I am expecting:** I am expecting the key will be replaced with the current value (e.g. 8). So that when I will again input something in my textbox (e.g. 12), it will be added with previous current value (e.g. 8, and then newValue will be 12+8).

**What I am getting:** Whenever I am clicking the button the key is set to 3 every time and adding with current value. But I want the key to be changed permanently or atleast be put aside after first use.

**Obligations:** The key value which is shown as 3 here has to be exactly as 3 when I am starting my program and clicking the send button for the first time. Actually I will be using the above concept for encryption/decryption later on [for building block I am using just an addition], so for the first time my key has to be known to the device, then the user can change it when she wants.

**Additional comment:** [My previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20653430/how-to-replace-the-variable-value-permanently) was almost similar but my requirement of updating the variable was still unfulfilled. The purpose was served though that time.

Comment: I've seen two approaches: 1) Use global variables, or 2) Use the `UserData` property (with get/set) of the handle passed to your callback.

Comment: Please reference and link to your previous (nearly identical) question in this new question and descirbe what is different and why the previous solutions have not worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a global variable for this.

Inside your main script, declare a global variable and assign 3 to it.

```
global key = 3;
```

Inside the function, first tell Matlab that you are using the global variable key. Then modify it as you want.

```
function send_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
     global key;   % Tell matlab to use the global varaible key instead of a new local variable.
     current = str2double(get(handles.value, 'String'));
     [newValue, key] = [key + current, current];
     % Do something with the newValue here...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use a global variable, add to your GUI initialization function:

```
handles.key = 3
guidata(hObject, handles)
```

And then use `handles.key` in place of `key` in your code, making sure to call `guidata(hOjbect, handles)` after the final assignment and before the function returns.  See http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/guidata.html , basically after setting a "variable" you're storing in `handles` (actually a field of the `handles` structure, I believe), you have to call `guidata()` to actually save the change.  This implies you're also passing `hObject`; I find the whole procedure to be such a pain I just revert to globals.